# Trying to use fetchSignInMethodForEmail

Tags: javascript, firebase, user-interface, firebase-authentication

I am trying to discover how to make a statement appear when someone registering to the form that I was made but the email address was already used. I am using firebase. I am not familiar with fetchSignInForEmail and am wondering how to use it and implement it.

I am thinking I can use an if statement

```
    if(email exists) {
     push firebase user to directed page
    } else {
     statement.style.display === block
    }
```

I am also curious on how to do this with passwords as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Listen for that error. However, I prefer to merge the accounts and let the user sign in. Below is an example snippet. [I've got this done for you](https://github.com/hightechtelecom/firebaselink), provided you want to allow email link authentication (no password required). Firebase offers a pre-rolled one as well that supports passwords and federation/oAuth (twitter, facebook, etc).

```
        } catch (error) {
            if(error.code === "auth/email-already-in-use"){
                // REMEMBER AUTH CURRENT USER OBJECT
                previousUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                // WE MUST HANDLE DB READ AND DELETE WHILE SIGNED IN AS PREVIOUS USER PER FIRESTORE SECURITY RULES
                if(localUserDoc){
                    if(localUserDoc.data().apples){
                        apples = localUserDoc.data().apples;
                    }                    
                }
                //DELETE CURRENT USER RECORD WHILE STILL SIGNED IN
                await firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(previousUser.uid).delete();
                // CLEAN UP DONE. NOW SIGN IN USING EMAIL LINK CREDENTIAL
                try {
                    var firebaseUserObj = await firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential);
                    // FIRESTORE USER RECORD FOR EMAIL LINK USER WAS CREATED WHEN THEY ADDED APPLE TO CART
                    try {
                        var doc = await firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(firebaseUserObj.user.uid).get();
                        if (doc.exists) {
                            if(doc.data().apples){
                                apples = apples + doc.data().apples;
                            }
                        }
                        await firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(firebaseUserObj.user.uid).update({
                            apples: apples
                        });
                    } catch(error) {
                        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
                    }
                    previousUser.delete();
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(".signInWithCredential err ", error);
                }
            }
        }
```